# How to find intersecting point of following type of functions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

We are given a function,$$f(x,y)=4x^2-xy+4y^2+x^3y+xy^3-4$$
Now to calculate minimum and maximum value of $f(x,y)$,
i first calculated $f_x$ and $f_y$ for stationary points.
which gave $$f_x=8x-y+3x^2y+y^3---(equation\ a)  $$ and $$f_y=-x+8y+x^3+3xy^2---(equation\ b)$$
$f_x=0\ and\ f_y=0$ gives the stationary point  but i am unable to find it. I tried substitution method but could not get a valid substitute, i also tried

$y*equation(a) - x*equation(b)$ 
which gave me $x^2-y^2+y^4-x^4=0,$ but it does not yield (1.5,-1.5) and (-1.5,1.5) which I obtained from graph,

how can i obtain intersection point without graphing?

graph at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5lficuv6ic

Comment: Do the operation $yf_x - xf_y = 0.$ Then either $x= \pm y.$ Which gives the stationary points $(0,0),\left ( \frac 3 2, -\frac 3 2 \right ), \left (-\frac 3 2, \frac 3 2 \right ).$

Comment: i have already done that, mentioned in question as well.

Comment: Or else you have to maximize or minimize $f$ subject to $x^2+y^2=1.$ Which can be done using Lagrange's method of undetermined multiplier.

Comment: Observe that $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2-1)(4+xy).$ So for all points on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ the function $f$ is identically $0.$

Comment: So the maximum value of $f$ is $\frac {49} {8}$ which is attained at the points $\left (\frac 3 2, -\frac 3 2 \right )$ and $\left (-\frac 3 2, \frac 3 2 \right )$ and the minimum value of $f$ is $-4$ which is attained at the point $(0,0).$

Answer (score 1):

$equation(a)+equation(b)$ $\Leftrightarrow$
$$(x+y)(x^2+2xy+y^2+7)=0$$
Then
$$x=-y$$

Answer (score 0):

If you make $y=x$ you would get
$$f_x=x \left(4 x^2+7\right)=0\implies x=0 \implies y= ???$$
If you make $y=-x$ you would get
$$f_x=9 x-4 x^3=0\implies x=\pm \frac 32\implies y= ???$$

Then, all the solutions.